# get values in List of Lists Java

Tags: java, list

I have a List of List array

```
List <List<String>> fname;

System.out.println(fname.get(0).get(0));-->gives 1st file name
```

I want to retrieve each element in the array List without using two for loop (as a solution I thought of)
 because it will increase the complexity any help??

Comment: hw is two loops going to increase the complexity?, you can just do `System.out.println(fname);` to print them all out? :)

Comment: when it will be two loop time complexity will be O(n^2)

Comment: I know this but I want to deal with each file name alone i.e store the file name that contain keyword in array2 forexample

Comment: You have a nested list. There may be a few syntactic tricks you could use to avoid having to write a nested loop, but ultimately, the runtime complexity won't change. The fact that the loop isn't evident in your code doesn't mean it's not there somewhere.

Comment: @Abeer a nested loop doesn't mean a time complexity of O(n^2). In fact the complexity will be O(n) in the number of elements.

Comment: @Abeer it will be O(n^2) , no matter what you use. you are goin to print n^2 items, thus it does n^2 times :D

Comment: Why is everyone saying O(n^2)? What is n?

Comment: @nafas, no, you are going to print n items, and the complexity is O(n).

Comment: @Abeer even if you do : System.out.println(fname); the complexity wil still be the same as it does it internally.

Comment: thanx for correcting my information I thought that each for loop will be a O(n) ,glade to post the question here

Comment: @davmac two lists mate, so here I assumed n  to be size of each. but you are right in a way. totalNumber of elements is the complexity

Comment: @Manu It's [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and 'n' is the size of the input, n^2 is 'n squared'.

Comment: @nafas there are m lists (for some m), mate, not two, and the number of items in total contained is n (for some n), which is not necessarily in the same order as m^2. Complexity is measured in terms of the size of the input, and that's n in this case.

Comment: @davmac mate, we are saying the same thing here,as I said I agreed with you, not sure why you are complicating things

Comment: @davmac I know Big-O notation. O(n^2) just doesn't make any sense without defining n.

Comment: @Manu when giving complexity of an algorithm, you generally do so in terms of a variable representing the size of the input (and it's often called 'n'). Without any other specified definition I'd normally feel safe to assume this one.

Comment: @davmac Agreed. And in this case, the input was a List of Lists. Thus, n is unclear: is it the size of the List? The average size of the Lists inside the List? The total amount of elements in the Lists? Without specifying this, O(n^2) has no meaning.

Comment: @Manu "the size of the input" refers to the total size of the input. In all truth this should probably account for each character in the strings, too (but then we can make certain reasonable assumptions which render this moot). I do not agree that it is unclear. n is, as always, the total size of the input. Regardless, given that OP clearly asks about processing each element, it seems like a good bet that n should at least be the number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that while this is one loop, it is much easier to do it with nested for loops

```
List<List<String>> list;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
while(x < list.size())
{
    if(y < list.get(x).size())
    {
        //do stuff with list.get(x).get(y)
        y++;
    }
    else
    {
        x++;
        y = 0;
    }
}
```

A much more preferred way to loop through all of the elements, and should be just as fast if not faster

```
List<List<String>> list;
for(List<String> l : list)
    for(String s : l)
        //do stuff with s
```

Comment: `if(y < list.size()` should be `if(y < list.get(x).size())`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you can simply use one statement:

```
fname.forEach(sublist -> sublist.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element)));
```

Comment: How is that not using two for-loops?

Comment: I was also thinking of some kind of streams, but even that is still pretty much nested looping

Comment: I'm not familiar with java 8 but I will learn about it thank  you for your note :)